# MySQL Update query takes more time to update the table

Tags: mysql, sql, performance, query-optimization

I wrote two mysql Queries.

First one:

```
SELECT I.Status FROM Test_chq_out_more100 O, chqinformore100 I
WHERE I.ACC_No = O.ACC_No  AND I.Chq_No = O.Begin_Chq_no;
```

Second one:

```
SELECT I.Status FROM Test_chq_out_more100 O, chqinformore100 I
WHERE I.ACC_No = O.ACC_No  AND I.Chq_No = (O.Begin_Chq_no + 1);
```

First query takes 05 seconds to get the answer but Second query takes 1165 Seconds to return the result. How can I optimize second query to get result within 10 - 15 seconds.

There are 2.5M records in chqinformore100 table and 11000 records in Test_chq_out_more100 table.

Comment: do you have indexes on I.Chq_No and O.Begin_Chq_no ?

Answer (score 2):

Here is the second query, "fixed" to use proper `join` syntax (which shouldn't affect the query plan):

```
SELECT I.Status
FROM Test_chq_out_more100 O JOIN
     chqinformore100 I
     ON I.ACC_No = O.ACC_No  AND I.Chq_No = (O.Begin_Chq_no + 1);
```

This query can be optimized by reading the `O` table and looking up values in the `I` table.  Hence, the index `Test_chq_out_more100(ACC_No, Chq_No)`.  However, it cannot take full advantage of an index on `chqinformore100(ACC_No, Begin_Chq_no)` because of the addition of 1.  So, my recommendation is to do one of the following:

One:  Keep the query as it is and create the index `Test_chq_out_more100(ACC_No, Chq_No)`.

Two:  Create the index `chqinformore100(ACC_No, Begin_Chq_no)` and change the query to:

```
SELECT I.Status
FROM Test_chq_out_more100 O JOIN
     chqinformore100 I
     ON I.ACC_No = O.ACC_No  AND I.Chq_No - 1 = O.Begin_Chq_no;
```